# How to use SSR or ISR with supabase?

Tags: next.js

How to do SSR here, and if someonce can clarify when to use SSR and ISR, that would be great?

I tried console logging but it doesn't show up at all, I have tried debugging this issue but haven't been able to resolve it.

Can someone please help me understand why getServerSideProps is not working as expected in my application? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!
I am allowing the consumer to add to transactions table this is the structure,

[image]

```
'use client'
// Import necessary modules and components
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import supabase from '../../config/supabaseConfig';


let userName = ''

// Define a functional component
const PaymentMade = ({ movies_data }) => {
  // Access the username from the Redux store
   userName = useSelector((state) => state.user.username);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Payment Made</h1>
      {movies_data?.length === 0 ? (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      ) : (
        movies_data?.map((movie_name) => (
          <h1 key={movie_name.movie_id}>{movie_name.movie_name}</h1>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Fetch transaction data using Supabase
    const { data: transaction, error } = await supabase
      .from('transaction')
      .select(`
        movie_id,
        movies (
          movie_name
        )
      `)
      .eq('user_email', userName); // Here, you need to define userName or fetch it from Redux
  
    return {
      props: {
        movies_data: transaction,
      },
    };
  }

export default PaymentMade;
```

Comment: You appear to be using the app router where `getServerSideProps` doesn't work. Do these answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76267351 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75119545